# When knitting HTML from Rmd file, datapoints in plot disappear

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

When I put together my Rmd-file for a report and print out the code, the plot appears exactly they I want it. But when I knit it to HTML, the datapoints in the plot disappear. Anyone with a potential idea, why this could be the case?

See my Rmd chunk below:

```
{r position_per_year, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, include=FALSE, fig.show='asis'}
# Position reached per year
position_2007 <- gp_2007 %>%
  group_by(location, surname) %>%
  summarise(position = as.numeric(positionText), .groups = "drop") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = location,
    y = position,
    group = surname,
    color = surname,
  )) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = seq(24, 1), limits = c(24,1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 90)) +
  xlab("GP Location") +
  ylab("Place reached")
```

In R-Markdown the plot appearing through

```
print(position_2007)
```

is as following:

[image: R-markdown output]

whereas when the plot is shown in the knitted HTML it looks like this (datapoints simply disappear):

[image: HTML knit output]

If someone has an idea on what could be the problem, this would be highly appreciated!

**Edit (on request):**

gp_2007 is the following dataframe:
[image]

```
dput(gp_2007)
```

delivers the following ouput:

```
structure(list(positionText = c("9", "3", "4", "R", "1", "3", 
"4", "1", "5", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "7", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
"3", "1", "2", "5", "7", "1", "1", "2", "3", "2", "2", "R", "7", 
"1", "2"), positionOrder = c(9L, 3L, 4L, 19L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 21L, 7L, 1L, 2L), points = c(0, 6, 5, 
0, 10, 6, 5, 10, 4, 10, 8, 6, 10, 8, 2, 8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 10, 8, 
4, 2, 10, 10, 8, 6, 8, 8, 0, 2, 10, 8), rank = c("3", "4", "4", 
"19", "1", "6", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "3", "1", "3", "1", 
"2", "2", "4", "3", "3", "1", "2", "4", "2", "2", "2", "1", "4", 
"2", "2", "2", "3", "2", "2"), year = c(2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L), round = c(10L, 8L, 14L, 16L, 5L, 
17L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 13L, 7L, 6L, 16L, 4L, 9L, 14L, 
1L, 15L, 13L, 3L, 17L, 7L, 10L, 2L, 12L, 1L, 5L, 15L, 8L, 2L, 
3L), gp = c("European Grand Prix", "French Grand Prix", "Belgian Grand Prix", 
"Chinese Grand Prix", "Monaco Grand Prix", "Brazilian Grand Prix", 
"Hungarian Grand Prix", "Hungarian Grand Prix", "Turkish Grand Prix", 
"Canadian Grand Prix", "British Grand Prix", "Spanish Grand Prix", 
"Italian Grand Prix", "United States Grand Prix", "Canadian Grand Prix", 
"Chinese Grand Prix", "Spanish Grand Prix", "British Grand Prix", 
"Belgian Grand Prix", "Australian Grand Prix", "Japanese Grand Prix", 
"Italian Grand Prix", "Bahrain Grand Prix", "Brazilian Grand Prix", 
"United States Grand Prix", "European Grand Prix", "Malaysian Grand Prix", 
"Turkish Grand Prix", "Australian Grand Prix", "Monaco Grand Prix", 
"Japanese Grand Prix", "French Grand Prix", "Malaysian Grand Prix", 
"Bahrain Grand Prix"), date = c("2007-07-22", "2007-07-01", "2007-09-16", 
"2007-10-07", "2007-05-27", "2007-10-21", "2007-08-05", "2007-08-05", 
"2007-08-26", "2007-06-10", "2007-07-08", "2007-05-13", "2007-09-09", 
"2007-06-17", "2007-06-10", "2007-10-07", "2007-05-13", "2007-07-08", 
"2007-09-16", "2007-03-18", "2007-09-30", "2007-09-09", "2007-04-15", 
"2007-10-21", "2007-06-17", "2007-07-22", "2007-04-08", "2007-08-26", 
"2007-03-18", "2007-05-27", "2007-09-30", "2007-07-01", "2007-04-08", 
"2007-04-15"), gp_place = c("Nürburgring", "Circuit de Nevers Magny-Cours", 
"Circuit de Spa-Francorchamps", "Shanghai International Circuit", 
"Circuit de Monaco", "Autódromo José Carlos Pace", "Hungaroring", 
"Hungaroring", "Istanbul Park", "Circuit Gilles Villeneuve", 
"Silverstone Circuit", "Circuit de Barcelona-Catalunya", "Autodromo Nazionale di Monza", 
"Indianapolis Motor Speedway", "Circuit Gilles Villeneuve", "Shanghai International Circuit", 
"Circuit de Barcelona-Catalunya", "Silverstone Circuit", "Circuit de Spa-Francorchamps", 
"Albert Park Grand Prix Circuit", "Fuji Speedway", "Autodromo Nazionale di Monza", 
"Bahrain International Circuit", "Autódromo José Carlos Pace", 
"Indianapolis Motor Speedway", "Nürburgring", "Sepang International Circuit", 
"Istanbul Park", "Albert Park Grand Prix Circuit", "Circuit de Monaco", 
"Fuji Speedway", "Circuit de Nevers Magny-Cours", "Sepang International Circuit", 
"Bahrain International Circuit"), location = c("Nürburg", "Magny Cours", 
"Spa", "Shanghai", "Monte-Carlo", "São Paulo", "Budapest", "Budapest", 
"Istanbul", "Montreal", "Silverstone", "Montmeló", "Monza", 
"Indianapolis", "Montreal", "Shanghai", "Montmeló", "Silverstone", 
"Spa", "Melbourne", "Oyama", "Monza", "Sakhir", "São Paulo", 
"Indianapolis", "Nürburg", "Kuala Lumpur", "Istanbul", "Melbourne", 
"Monte-Carlo", "Oyama", "Magny Cours", "Kuala Lumpur", "Sakhir"
), country = c("Germany", "France", "Belgium", "China", "Monaco", 
"Brazil", "Hungary", "Hungary", "Turkey", "Canada", "UK", "Spain", 
"Italy", "USA", "Canada", "China", "Spain", "UK", "Belgium", 
"Australia", "Japan", "Italy", "Bahrain", "Brazil", "USA", "Germany", 
"Malaysia", "Turkey", "Australia", "Monaco", "Japan", "France", 
"Malaysia", "Bahrain"), forename = c("Lewis", "Lewis", "Lewis", 
"Lewis", "Fernando", "Fernando", "Fernando", "Lewis", "Lewis", 
"Lewis", "Fernando", "Fernando", "Fernando", "Fernando", "Fernando", 
"Fernando", "Lewis", "Lewis", "Fernando", "Lewis", "Lewis", "Lewis", 
"Fernando", "Lewis", "Lewis", "Fernando", "Lewis", "Fernando", 
"Fernando", "Lewis", "Fernando", "Fernando", "Fernando", "Lewis"
), surname = c("Hamilton", "Hamilton", "Hamilton", "Hamilton", 
"Alonso", "Alonso", "Alonso", "Hamilton", "Hamilton", "Hamilton", 
"Alonso", "Alonso", "Alonso", "Alonso", "Alonso", "Alonso", "Hamilton", 
"Hamilton", "Alonso", "Hamilton", "Hamilton", "Hamilton", "Alonso", 
"Hamilton", "Hamilton", "Alonso", "Hamilton", "Alonso", "Alonso", 
"Hamilton", "Alonso", "Alonso", "Alonso", "Hamilton"), name = c("McLaren", 
"McLaren", "McLaren", "McLaren", "McLaren", "McLaren", "McLaren", 
"McLaren", "McLaren", "McLaren", "McLaren", "McLaren", "McLaren", 
"McLaren", "McLaren", "McLaren", "McLaren", "McLaren", "McLaren", 
"McLaren", "McLaren", "McLaren", "McLaren", "McLaren", "McLaren", 
"McLaren", "McLaren", "McLaren", "McLaren", "McLaren", "McLaren", 
"McLaren", "McLaren", "McLaren")), row.names = c(13L, 41L, 44L, 
89L, 132L, 150L, 159L, 231L, 251L, 305L, 314L, 315L, 341L, 361L, 
363L, 384L, 387L, 430L, 466L, 486L, 493L, 512L, 581L, 599L, 635L, 
649L, 672L, 704L, 759L, 768L, 769L, 801L, 826L, 838L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Edit 2 (on request):**

The dataframe "Hamilton_Alonso" looks as following (screenshot only shows first 43 of 668 rows):
[image]

Comment: If you restart your R session, and execute the code in your chunks manually, do you have the same problem? If not, it's probably because you did something manually but not in the Rmd file that would lead to a difference in behaviour. If so, we'd need more information in order to reproduce the problem, including the data as used for the chart using `dput()`.

Comment: So basically I execute chunk by chunk in the Rmd file and then the output is the desired plot. Only when knitting it to HTML they datapoints disappear. I didn't change anything and especially when running it in the Rmd file and it works it shouldn't change when being knitted to HTML.
Regarding data - it is the data from Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rohanrao/formula-1-world-championship-1950-2020) and I want to show how for each season since 2007 Hamilton and Alonso scored points and what position they ended in. Hope that answers your questions.

Comment: It appears that the problem is somewhere _before_ the code you're showing us. I'm with @Phil, though, often it is because the user is not using [parameterized reports](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html) (correctly or at all), causing a change in behavior. If not a change in how data is made available, it could be in the presence/order of packages (e.g., `plyr`-vs-`dplyr`, though I don't think that is likely to be the issue here). More context to the document would be useful here.

Comment: @JeffreySachs Could you provide more information? There are multiple data frames provided here, and while I could work out which ones you used to get to this point, i don't feel it's on me to take the time to do so. Again, the quickest thing to do really is to run `dput(gp_2007)` and include the output as part of your question.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem: https://i.imgur.com/MmRJvDD.png

Comment: @Phil As mentioned, when executing it in my RStudio as chunk of my Rmd file, I dont have the problem either. When knitting it to HTML, the datapoints disappear. I now uploaded with all the code and outputs, how my HTML file looks - [link](https://rpubs.com/jeffsachs/1002469)

Comment: The image I provided is the HTML file that was knitted.

Comment: @JeffreySachs Could you provide the output of `dput(Hamilton_Alonso)`? I'll try to rearrange your code a bit to sidestep this issue.

Comment: @Phil I added a screenshot of the dataframe as I can't put the output of `dput(Hamilton_Alonso)` as body is limited to 30'000 characters. I really appreciate your help and the time you are taking on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without data to test, I'm doing this blindly. The point is to remove the duplication of the same code for each year by using `purrr::map()` to run the same bit of code for each year.

Then for the chart, I'd recommend using `patchwork` instead of `gridExtra` to combine charts together.

```
library(purrr)

Hamilton_Alonso_plot_dfl <- Hamilton_Alonso |> 
  filter(year %in% c(2007:2018, 2021:2022)) |>
  group_split(year) |> 
  map(function(x) { x |> 
    group_by(location, surname) |> 
      summarise(total_points = sum(points), 
                position = as.numeric(positionText),
                .groups = "drop")
  })

library(patchwork)

make_charts <- function(x, year) {
  points_chart <- ggplot(x, aes(
      x = location,
      y = total_points,
      group = surname,
      color = surname
    )) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = surname), position = position_dodge2(width = 0.5, preserve = "single"), stat = "identity", alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_smooth(se = FALSE) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 50, 1), limits = c(0,25)) +
    scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 90)) +
    xlab("GP Location") +
    ylab("Points collected")
  
 positions_chart <- ggplot(x, aes(
   x = location,
   y = position,
   group = surname,
   color = surname,
 )) +
   geom_point() +
   geom_line() +
   scale_y_reverse(breaks = seq(24, 1), limits = c(24,1)) +
   scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 90)) +
   xlab("GP Location") +
   ylab("Place reached") 
 
 points_chart + positions_chart + plot_annotation(title = year)
}

map2(Hamilton_Alonso_plot_dfl, c(2007:2018, 2021:2022), make_charts)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because of certain missing values leading to vectors of unequal length and ultimately therefore in a recycling error of type:
`Error in map2():
! Can't recycle .x (size 21) to match .y (size 14).
Backtrace:
 1. purrr::map2(Hamilton_Alonso_plot_dfl, c(2007:2018, 2021:2022), positions_chart)`
Nevertheless I highly appreciate the effort you made!

Comment: Added a `filter()` line to force it to match.

Comment: ```map2(Hamilton_Alonso_plot_dfl, c(2007:2018, 2021:2022), positions_chart)```
now results in the error
```Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : object 'positions_chart' not found
3.
as_mapper(.f, ...)
2.
map2_("list", .x, .y, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
1.
map2(Hamilton_Alonso_plot_dfl, c(2007:2018, 2021:2022), positions_chart)
```
@Phil

Comment: So sorry - brain fart on my part. The last line should be calling `make_charts` not `positions_chart`. I made the revision above.